# ¿Cómo exportar/importar una función prototype?

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-import, prototipos

Lo he intentado de mil maneras y no veo forma de leer la función `prototipo`
¿Cómo tengo que exportar/importar la función?

Tengo dos archivos:
Archivo1: **index.ts**

```
export class Tabla{
    valor:number;
    constructor(valor:number){
        this.valor = valor;
    }
    muestra(){};
};

class Ventana extends Tabla{};
const tablero = new Ventana(2);

Tabla.prototype.muestra(); // muestra en consola '1'
tablero.muestra(); // muestra en consola '2'
```

Tengo el prototipo en este otro archivo:
Archivo2: **muestra.ts**

```
import {Tabla} from './index';

Tabla.prototype.muestra = function():void{
    Tabla.prototype.valor = 1;
    console.log(this.valor);
}
```

Comment: Esto ya se ha respondido en otro hilo.
Solución:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699889/es6-declare-a-prototype-method-on-a-class-with-an-import-statement

Comment: Podrías auto-responder tu pregunta, explicando como lograste solucionarlo

Comment: @Storko Acabo de entrar a tu enlace, la respuesta corresponde al sitio en inglés, algunas personas en inglés no nos defendemos mucho que digamos. por lo que una explicación (aunque sea derivada de la referida) en castellano (español) sería adecuada.